# How to show login error with AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I am fairly new to Java and I have a spring app. For the logging-in feature I'm using AuthenticationProvider. However, I am unable to show the custom error message if the authentication is not successful. It logs the correct message, but I'm unable to pass it to the view.

```
// CustomAuthenticationProvider.java
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    UserAuthenticationRequest loginRequest = new UserAuthenticationRequest(name, password);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
      .register(JacksonConfig.class)
      .register(JacksonFeature.class)
      .build();

    Invocation.Builder request = client.target(apiBaseUrl)
      .path("login")
      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      
    Response response = request.post(Entity.json(loginRequest));
    
    if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
      return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>());
    } else {
      ExceptionResponse errorResponse = response.readEntity(ExceptionResponse.class);
      return null;          
    }
  }
}
```

If I log `errorResponse.getMessage()` - I get the message I need, but how do I pass it to the view? I'm already showing a generic message if there's a param `?error`.

So far I tried to add it to Model, save it to session but it threw an error 500 each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you probably should make custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` to handle `AuthenticationException` thrown in `AuthenticationProvider`.

```java
public class CustomHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                        AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

Then you can manipulate with the response.

You have to register it in your security configuration `http.formLogin().failureHandler(new CustomHandler());`.

**EDIT 1**

Throw one of implementations of `AuthenticationException`.

```java
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong credentials");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction, I tried to make it like that, but every message I get (from `e.getMessage()`) is `no authentication provider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. I still don't see how to get my `AuthenticationException`in the `CustomHandler`

Comment: You should throw by yourself an exception in `AuthenticationProvider ` with the desired message. I've added an example to my original answer.